# How to hide group column headers in a FastReport drill down grouped report when the group is collapsed?

Tags: fastreport

Using FastReport 4 with Delphi 2009.

I have a simple drill down grouped report (ie groupheader1.drilldown = true) running from a single data set with a group header followed by a master data band.

The group header has some memos with overall group data and the master band has some memos with data from that group.

To get column headers for the individual items with each group when the group is expanded I've put some memos with plain text in them at the bottom of the group header. (shown highlighted in red in the first image)

This works fine when the group is expanded but looks strange when I collapse the group as I still see a column header for each group, even though the data is collapsed. (see second image)

Is there a better way to make the column headers for the expanded data such that they only appear when the data itself if expanded?

**This is the report design**
[image: report design]

**This is what it looks like with the groups collapsed (note you can see all the column headers)**

[image]

**This is what it looks like with one of the groups expanded (that group looks OK but the others look odd)**

[image]

Answer (score 0):

To assist anyone else looking at this I have found the answer to be the following.

1. Add a second group header underneath the first one with the same
   condition as the first one.
2. Put the col headers in the lower group header and leave the memos
   with summary group info in the upper one.
3. Set DrillDown := true for upper group header and false for the lower
   one.

**so the design will look like...**

[image]